# How to calculate current-1 year in tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I am using Tableau 8.2,I want to show calculations for current as well as previous year,how to apply this dynamically? it is getting possible if the year is written manually but it will be only temporary solution, how to do that dynamically?
i.e on applying filter Year=2013 then sales and orders value of current-1 year should be displayed
I have sales and orders On the Columns.

Comment: Best way to do that is using a parameter. Then create a calculated field like YEAR(date) = Parameter - 1

Comment: Thanks, but I need to include current year as well, I have calculated the current year by int(DATENAME('year',today() )), but the Gray area being is if my calculations are taking 2013 as the current year, then how are we supposed to calculate the current year for 2013 or any other year as the current year. I need some leads for the same. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Man, I understood nothing on this comment, try to edit the question with a better text. In the mean time, to filter in current year and last year, just YEAR(date) = Parameter - 1 OR YEAR(date) = Parameter.

Answer (score 1):

A quick solution to this would be to create a new calculated field for previous year sales by using the Lookup function.

For example:

**`LOOKUP(SUM([SALES]),-1)`**

Answer (score 0):

You can simply introduce two calculated fields which will give you the current and previous year. These can be used on the rows and columns shelves or any where else depending on whether your aiming for chart, text table or any other viz.

Calculated field 1 = Current Filter
if datediff('year',[Date],TODAY() )=0  **then 1**
ELSE 0 
END

Calculated field 2 = Previous Filter
if datediff('year',[Date],TODAY() )=1  **then 1**
ELSE 0 
END

The formulas above can be used if the required measure is just a count otherwise you could replace: **then 1**  with **then [Amount]** or whatever measure this applies to.

Answer (score 0):

Create a parameter and use `IF Year = 'Parameter Value'THEN Sales ELSE 0 END`

or use LOD to know the Max Year if you want it to be more dynamic: `IF Year = {FIXED: MAX([Year])} THEN Sales ELSE 0 END`