# How to display previous year data

Tags: tableau-api

I have a year drop down with 2013 and 2014.So when I select 2014 from the drop down.It should display 2013 data i.e. previous year data,Similarly when I select 2015 from the drop down.It should display 2014 data..

How do I write the calculations for this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to calculate current-1 year in tableau](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27008303/how-to-calculate-current-1-year-in-tableau)

Comment: Do you really believe that asking the same question again will get a different result. As posted the answer is still the same, create a parameter [Year], then create a calculated field YEAR([Date]) = [Year]-1, and use it as filter. But on the other question you added some complications that was impossible to understand. Try to better explain what you need

Answer (score 0):

Create a parameter and in Filter of Year Field use condition as:

```
YEAR = PARMETERYEAR-1
```

or if it is a date Filed

```
use datediff('Year',filterdate)
```

Comment: You can put your email and telephone in your profile, not your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever possible, you should avoid the use of parameters. Parameters are good for going across data sources, but as of the current version, still have a number of limitations such as the ability to only do a single select.

What you're asking for can be accomplished with a simple alias.  Just right click on the dimension and select 'Alias'

[image]